# Strange behaviour on custom NavBar for Titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium, custom-controls, appcelerator, navbar

First of all, please don't recommend me to use the native iOS/Android objects, this is a test about custom controls and I need it to work.

I'm encountering a strange behavior while using a custom Navbar in Android or iOS. All seems to be right until I close a window directly (by code) in the custom navBar. The secont time I open another window with the navBar, the old objects (label, buttons, etc.) are still there.
I post an example:
First, from a main window I call the AddForm in the NavBar:

```
var ui = require('navigation');
var nav = ui.createNavigatorGroup();

Alloy.Globals.navBar = nav;

nav.open(winAddPill, {animated: true});
```

[image: initial data]

When user press ADD button (you can't see, is in bottom of a form), I autoclose the window in the nav, after save the data, with this code:

`Alloy.Globals.navBar.close($.win);`

If I do that, when now I call another window, e.g., show info (which has a DELETE button in right), the title label is mixed with previous window:

```
Alloy.Globals.navBar.open(winPill, {animated: true});
```

[image: mixed data]

As you can see, all is mixed, this is what must be shown instead:
[image: right image]

If I continue to open new windows, all is still mixing.
Any help to avoid this behavior? I was fighting with this problem 4 days and don't find the solution.

Finally, the custom navBar that I'm using:

```
exports.createNavigatorGroup = function() {
     var me = {};

        var navViews = []; // A stack of navigation bars
        var navView;

        function pushNavBar() {
            navView = Ti.UI.createView({
                top: 0,
                height: 44,
                backgroundColor: '#BBB'
            });
            navViews.push(navView);
        };

        function popNavBar() {
            navViews.pop();
            navView = navViews[navViews.length - 1];
        };

        // Make sure we always have a navView available to prepare
        pushNavBar();

        me.open = function(win) {
            navView.add(Ti.UI.createLabel({
                text: win.title,
                color: 'black'
            }));

            navView.win = win;
            win.add(navView);

            win.navBarHidden = true;
            win.open();

        // Prepare for the next window
            pushNavBar();
        };

        me.close = function(win) {
            if (navViews.length > 1) {
                // Close the window on this nav
                popNavBar();
                win.close();
            }
        };
    return me;
};
```

Also I added a simple and runable project in GitHub with only 3 empty windows for testing. You can see the question [here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/156532/custom-navigation-bar-problems-with-android#comment-187529) and the project is [here](https://github.com/mcvendrell/Basic-custom-NavBar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the f*****g problem!!!

I analized with detail the code and found it. All the problem resides in that a new navView is always prepared for config new objects, so, lets say, we have 2 windows opened, then we have 3 navViews. The number 3 is clear, nothing inside, just ready to setLeftButton before open new window with it.

But if we close the actual window, with the navView 2 with objects, the code makes "popNavView" that only remove the last (empty) navView 3 and SETS the actual navView 2 as ready to use... **with all its actual objects inside**.

The simple solution is... remove it after set, with this simple line inside popNavBar:

```
function popNavBar() {
      navViews.pop();
      navView = navViews[navViews.length - 1];
      navView.removeAllChildren();
};
```

I will re-do the github code to let it available for others who wants to use a functional custom NavBar.